# Google Calendar Date Issue - End dates always incorrect

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I am having an issue with the correct dates being pulled down from the Google calendar event API.   The problem is related to the end date not being correct.   For example, the Google Calendar event for a block might run from 8:30-10, but the event is coming as 8:30 - 7:00.   This is affecting all of the results of our request.   The code looks like this:

```
function listUpcomingEvents() {
        gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
          'calendarId': 'atomic55.net_7smfqj9jlem68s42unp0ubr9js@group.calendar.google.com',
          'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
          'showDeleted': false,
          'singleEvents': true,
          'maxResults': 150,
          'orderBy': 'startTime'
        }).then(function(response) {
```

The information coming back is (sample):

Upcoming events:

- ADS (2020-08-27T15:30:00-**07:00**)
- Junk Drawer (2020-08-28T07:30:00-**07:00**)
- Lead Download (2020-08-28T09:00:00-**07:00**)
- Client X (2020-08-28T09:30:00-**07:00**)
- PHONE/COMMUNICATION (2020-08-28T12:30:00-**07:00**)

The start time is accurate, but the end time is not (notice how all of the end dates are 7:00).   Any idea why this could be the case?

Comment: sounds like an issue with the time zone the API is going to return the results in what ever time zone the calendar is set to.  Try doing a calendar.get on that calendar id to see what timezone its set to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but if it was a timezone issue why would the start time be accurate, but the endtime incorrect?   I will check tho.

Comment: Please edit your question include The result from calendar.get.  so we can see the time zone its set.   Then include the full response from the the API as well as a look at what is set in your calendar.   Your code looks right something else is effecting the results.  My only guess would be time zone.

Comment: How did you create those events? What do they look like in the calendar UI? can you post the complete response for an event?

Comment: Hi Ryan55, when you want to provide additional information, you need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63625509/edit) you quesiton rather than providing it as an asnwer. Also, by complete response I mean the complete JSON response you obtain when listing / getting your event, you can specify `'fields':'*'`. Also: do you have hte same problem when using `events.get` instead of `events.list`? Did you create the event via Calendar API, via Claendar UI or via athid party?

Comment: I am pulling the events via the API. 
        var timeval = "2020-01-01T19:27:05+0000";
        gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
          'calendarId': 'atominp0ubr9js@group.calendar.google.com',
          'timeMin': timeval,
          'showDeleted': false,
          'singleEvents': true,
          'maxResults': 2500,
          'orderBy': 'startTime'
        }).then(function(response) {
          var events = response.result.items;
          appendPre('Upcoming Projects:');

Comment: I do not know what your function `appendPre()` is doing, but what about incorporating the following logs for troubleshooting? `events.forEach(function(event){
       console.log(event.start.date);
       console.log(event.start.dateTime);
       console.log(event.start.timeZone);       
       console.log(event.end.date);
       console.log(event.end.dateTime);
       console.log(event.end.timeZone);
     });`

Comment: Thank you Ziganotschka.   This helped me to solve the problem.  The issue was related to this variable: var when = event.start.dateTime; I needed to also incorporate this one: console.log(event.end.dateTime);

Comment: Glad your issue was solved. Would you consider posting an answer explaining what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses.   Attached is the output of one event specifically to be compared to.  As you can see the time in the UI is set to be from 9-10PST which is correct; however, the query to the API is returning:

Steve Cartner Project End:  (2020-09-16T09:00:00-**07:00**)

https://preview55.com/ryan/gantt/projectoutput.PNG
https://preview55.com//ryan/gantt/Capture-projectend.PNG

Answer (score 0):

The `-07:00` isn't the end time, it's the time zone offset. See [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC)